# Groupby multiindex columns using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby, multi-index

On a DataFrame with single levels, group the data on columns using a dictionary:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])
dict_col= {'a':'ab','b':'ab','c':'c','d':'d','e':'efgh','f':'efgh','g':'efgh','h':'efgh'}
df1.groupby(dict_col, axis=1).sum()
    ab          c           d           efgh
A   1.014831    1.274621    -1.490353   -0.954438
B   1.484857    -0.968642   0.700881    -3.281607
C   0.898556    1.444362    0.680974    -2.985182
```

On a MultiIndexed DataFrame:

```
MultiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 32), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=MultiIndex)
df2.groupby(dict_col, axis=1, level=1).sum()
    ab          c           d           efgh
A   6.583721    -1.554734   1.922187    1.100208
B   6.138441    0.653721    -0.204472   1.890755
C   0.951489    2.695940    -1.494028   0.907464
```

How to get something like this (All elements on level 0)?

```
    bar                                            baz                                              foo
    ab          c           d           efgh       ab           c           d           efgh        ......    
A   6.583721    -1.554734   1.922187    1.100208   4.944954     -1.343831   0.939265    -3.614612   ......
B   6.138441    0.653721    -0.204472   1.890755   -0.347505    1.633708    0.392096    0.414880    ......
C   0.951489    2.695940    -1.494028   0.907464   1.905409     -1.021097   -2.399670   0.799798    ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to pass a function to `groupby`, and then convert the tuples back to MultiIndex

```
out = df2.groupby(lambda x: (x[0], dict_col[x[1]]), axis=1).sum()
out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(out.columns)
```

Another way is flatten the column levels by `stack` then `unstack` back after `groupby`:

```
df2.stack(level=0).groupby(dict_col, axis=1).sum().unstack(level=-1)
```